# How can I configure the following route? - Imply action method from URL pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a `ProgramController` which contains several action methods for edition, like `EditDetails`, `EditContacts`, `EditRules` (plus 10 more but I will exclude them for simplicity). Currently the URLs for this actions methods look something like the following:

```
http://localhost/Program/1/EditContacts
http://localhost/Program/1/EditDetails
http://localhost/Program/1/EditRules
```

But I want them to look like the following:

```
http://localhost/Program/1/Contacts/Edit
http://localhost/Program/1/Details/Edit
http://localhost/Program/1/Rules/Edit
```

Which makes more sense to me.

So far this is my `RegisterRoutes` method:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");            

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProgramInfo",
            url: "Program/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Program"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProgramDefault",
            url: "Program/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Program", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

The only way I have found so far to achieve this is to have a route for each action method, like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "EditContacts",
    url: "Program/{id}/Contacts/Edit",
    defaults: new { controller = "Program", action = "EditContacts" }
);
```

But I'm trying to find a better solution to avoid repetition. Something like the following crossed my mind but it's **incorrect**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "EditProgram",
    url: "Program/{id}/{variable}/Edit",
    defaults: new { controller = "Program", action = "Edit" + "{variable}" }
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to push your Contacts in the Contacts controller, Details in the details controller etc. It fits naturally with how you are describing your url space.

If you want another level of indirection you can use Areas.

Note: You can implement your own RouteHandler or your own route based on RouteBase, but it seems like a really big hammer for your question.

Here is a link to such an approach:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=970

Answer (score 0):

You will need to translate incoming route values to existing /controller/action/id.

Step 1: Create custom route handler to translate routing

```
public class ReWriteUrlRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    private string _controllerName;

    public ReWriteUrlRouteHandler(string controllerName)
    {
        _controllerName = controllerName;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var routeValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
        var id = routeValues["id"];
        var action = routeValues["action"];
        var task = routeValues["task"];
        var defaultAction = string.Format("{0}{1}", task, action);

        //translate to default handler
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = _controllerName;
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = defaultAction;
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] = id;

        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Register Route in route table global.asax.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    var programRoute = new Route("Program/{id}/{action}/{task}", new ReWriteUrlRouteHandler("Program"));//your new route with controller name
    routes.Add("ProgramRoute", programRoute);


    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it works when I navigate to a URL like http://localhost/Program/1/Contacts/Edit, it doesn't generate the links correctly, if I use Html.ActionLink(...) it will generate the URL in the format http://localhost/Program/EditContact/1.